# Django custom management command not found

Tags: django

```
app/
├─ management/
│  ├─ commands/
│  │  ├─ customcommand.py
myfunction.py
site/
├─ settings.py
```

Content of settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
  ]
}
```

Content of customcommand.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import time
import requests

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("execued the commands success!!")
        start_time = time.time()

        for number in range(1, 50):
            url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            resp = requests.get(url)
            pokemon = resp.json()
            print(pokemon['name'])

        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Contents of myfunction.py

```
from django.core import management

def funcA():
    management.call_command('customcommand')

funcA()
```

On calling myfunction.py from terminal it throws **raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)**

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'site.settings'
```

Inside myfunction.py I have tried setting this, but it still doesn't work. Can someone help me out here, probably I am missing out on some important config

Comment: Can you post the content of `customcommand.py` ?

Comment: Please show your settings. Are you loading the app config correctly in settings.py? For example: `INSTALLED_APPS = ['apps.commands.apps.CommandsConfig']`?... I have the same structure in my project where all apps go in an `apps` dir

Comment: Hi @AlexanderSchillemans, I have posted the content of customcommand.py

Comment: @ViaTech app here is a django app and not a folder where all the apps reside. The app folder contains more files like views, urls, etc. For simplicity I have mentioned only the commands folder in the folder structure. I have included the app in the installed app settings.

Comment: @ViaTech I have uploaded the contents of my settings.py for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the django.setup() call, after configuring the environment variable.

Inside myfunction.py, the following changes should be made

```
from django.core import management
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'site.settings')

django.setup()

def funcA():
    management.call_command('customcommand')

funcA()
```

django.setup() is essential to include because it registers your applications and commands defined in your settings in a standalone script which the manage.py or django-admin takes care usually

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `__init__.py` to `management/` and `commands/` directories.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work